# Get result by joining with JSON Object Key of a column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

**points** table - columns: id, json_column

```
[
 {"user_id":"1","points":"1"},
 {"user_id":"2","points":"1"},
 {"user_id":"3","points":"0"},
]
```

**users** table - columns: id, name

```
1 | steve
2 | matthew
3 | john
```

Expected result. All users with points using eloquent

```
1-steve-1
2-matthew-1
3-john-0

$users=User::all();
```

Is it possible to get the output using **with** statement

Edit:

Point model

```
protected $casts = [
        'json_column' => 'json'
 ];
```

user model

```
 public function point()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Point::class, 'json_column->user_id', 'id');
}
```

Printed query - but it returns null:

```
select * 
from `points` 
where json_unquote(json_extract(`points`.`json_column`, '$."user_id"')) in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
```

This works if a single json array is in column :

```
{"user_id":"1","points":"1"}
```

If it contains array of arrays, code doesn't work

```
[
 {"user_id":"1","points":"1"},
 {"user_id":"2","points":"1"},
 {"user_id":"3","points":"0"},
]
```

Edit 2:
casted as array. but doesnt working

```
 protected $casts = [
        'application_data' => 'array'
    ];
```

Comment: Yes. It is possible according to your query

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible, assuming you already have **User** and **Point** models created:

**USER modal**

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $guarded = [];


    public function point()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Point::class, 'json_column->user_id');
    }
}
```

**POINT modal**

```
class Point extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'points';

    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $casts = [
        'json_column' => 'json'
    ];

}
```

then you can eager load the users point using with